# How to get Chrome to load certain pages after a delay on startup?

Tags: google-chrome

I use Chrome daily, and have 10 pages setup as start up pages, so whenever Chrome is started, it automatically tries to load these 10 pages. This of course is a slow process, and I don't always want these pages loaded, sometimes I only want a new tab on startup.

To have the best of both worlds, I'd like to delay loading each page on startup. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find a Chrome extension to do this, but couldn't fine one. Then it occurred to me that I could use a simple HTML page that's stored locally on my hard drive, and have it redirect using javascript after a configurable delay.

So instead of my startup pages being set to:

```
https://www.farnamstreetblog.com/blog/
http://hackaday.com/blog
```

I now set them to this, and can easily control how long it takes each page to load, without needing an extension at all, and actually this of course works with any browser, not just Chrome.

Just edit the urls below, and save the page as an html page on your hard drive, and then double click on it to open it. Then make that link in the address bar a start page, and you're done!

### open_pages_on_start.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Open Pages</title>

  <style>
    * {
        font-family:arial;
    }

    body {background-color: #FFFFF0;}

  </style>

  <script>
    // CHANGE THE FOLLOWING AS YOU SEE FIT
    // Currently waits 5 seconds before starting to open pages
    var numSecondsBetweenPageOpens = 5;
    var urls = [
      {url:'https://live.givedirectly.org/'},
      {url:'https://www.damninteresting.com/'}
    ];

    var initialDelay = 0;
    var elapsedTime = 0;
    var currDelay = 1;
    var enabled = true;
    var firstTime = true;

    function getOutput(value)
    {
      return document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
    }

    function setOutput(value)
    {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = value;
    }

    function out(msg)
    {
      var html = getOutput();
      setOutput(msg + '<br/>' + html);
    }

    function stopIt()
    {
      enabled = ! enabled;
      if (! enabled)
      {
        out("<h3>Stopped!</h3>");
      }
      else
      {
        main();
        out("<h3>Started!</h3>");
      }

    }

    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    function nvl(value,defaultValue)
    {
      if (value == null)
        return defaultValue;
      if (value == "")
        return defaultValue;
      if (value)
        return value;
      return defaultValue;
    }

    var url = getParameterByName('url');
    var showInfoDelay = nvl(parseInt(getParameterByName('showInfoDelay')), 1) * 1000;

    document.title=url;

    setInterval(function()
    {
      if (! enabled)
        return;

      out(elapsedTime);
      elapsedTime++;
    }, 1000);

    function doIt(item)
    {
      currDelay = currDelay + numSecondsBetweenPageOpens;
      var seconds = nvl(parseInt(currDelay+initialDelay));

      out('Opening <a href="' + item.url + '">' + item.url + '</a> in ' + seconds + ' seconds.');
      setTimeout(function()
      {
        if (! enabled)
          return;
        out('Opening ' + item.url);
        window.open(item.url);
      }, seconds * 1000);
    }

    function main()
    {
      setTimeout(function()
      {
        setOutput('');
        for (var i=0; i < urls.length; i++)
        {
          var item = urls[i];
          doIt(item);
        }
      }, showInfoDelay);
    }

  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <p>Will start to open pages soon.</p>
  <p> <a href="javascript:stopIt()">Click to stop opening pages</a> </p>
  <div id="output">...<br/></div>
  <script>
    main();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```